# MySQL where date is between two timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to select all date between to dates/times. Unfortunately i get no resolute. I have seen a lot of examples where people try to select data between ex. '2012-08-27' without the time. I need the time as well.

Here is my query. Can anyone tell me whats wrong? The row date has the timestamp as datatype.

```
SELECT date, points 
FROM nf_publicpoints 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-08-27 00:00:00' AND '2012-08-02 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY points DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Thanks in advance
Troels

Answer (score 1):

try using `DATE` function

```
WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '2012-08-02' AND '2012-08-27'
```

if you need time,

```
WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-08-02 00:00:00' AND '2012-08-27 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no syntax issue on that query.
I think you simply have to turn around your query like so:

```
SELECT date, points 
FROM nf_publicpoints 
#canged that                ||                        ||
WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-08-02 00:00:00' AND '2012-08-27 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY points DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

The time has to be ginven in increasing order, as there is no time between 27 and 02 of August, but there is one between 02 and 27.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ye, i know :) just saw it. But it will not change anything.

Comment: Sorry, you are running mysql, right? And the fields are DATETIME or TIMESTAMP types, right? This answer works for me.